# Ускорить выполнение запроса Mysql

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица в ней примерно полтора миллиона записей.
Делаю выборку, время работы запроса примерно 10 секунд.

```
select country, count(id) as total_leads 
from users 
where op_status = 1 
group by country 
order by total_leads desc
```

поле country и op_status проиндексированны.
Если спросить так:

```
select country, count(id) as total_leads 
from users  
group by country 
order by total_leads desc
```

то время выполнения 0.4 сек
Не пойму почему так вырастает время выполнения запроса, оба поля индексные. Что можно сделать чтобы запрос выполнялся быстрее?

Comment: *поле country и op_status проиндексированны* По отдельности, что ли? толку-то с того индексирования... *Что можно сделать чтобы запрос выполнялся быстрее?* `CREATE INDEX idx ON users(op_status,country)`. Только если  на каждый запрос создавать оптимальный для него индекс - в итоге получится голимая хрень, безнадёжно тормозная на корректировках данных.

Comment: Чтобы не гадать, в phpMyAdmin есть профилирование запроса, где можно увидеть время на каждую операцию MySQL.

Comment: Да, дайте вывод explain для обоих запросов

Comment: Да индекс по отдельности. Хорошо, если это решение как вы говорите тормознутое, есть способ получить эти же данные другим способом и быстрее?

Comment: тогда индекс объедините. И никогда не делайте отдельных индексов, одно уникальное значение в которых покрывает собой более 10% таблицы, такие индексы замедляют выборку если оптимизатору вдруг придет в голову их использовать